# How to make this jquery var shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make this variable shorter?

```
var outskirts = ((jQuery("#billing\\:city").val() == "Manila")||(jQuery("#billing\\:city").val() == "Quezon City"))
```

I already tried:

```
var outskirts = ((jQuery("#billing\\:city").val() == "Manila" || "Quezon City"))
```

And I also tried:

```
var outskirts = (jQuery("#billing\\:city").val() == ("Manila") || ("Quezon City"))
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the value in a variable first.

```
const val = jQuery("#billing\\:city").val();
const outskirts = val === "Manila" || val === "Quezon City";
```

In most cases, jQuery will be aliased to `$`, so the following will probably work too:

```
const val = $("#billing\\:city").val();
```

You could also do

```
const outskirts = ['Manila', 'Quezon City'].includes($("#billing\\:city").val());
```

Comment: Ooohhh.... Thanks.

Can I still make that even shorter? Like remove the val? Because it's redundant.

Like const outskirts = (Manila, Quezon City, And so on).

Comment: You can use the `.includes` method as shown at the bottom, but I'd really prefer to extract the value first, I think it's more readable. Readability is much more important than conserving lines of code.

Comment: The second option seems to be much better. Thank you so much! Damn, I'm so dumb I haven't figured this out for days.
const outskirts = ['Manila', 'Quezon City'].includes($("#billing\\:city").val());

Comment: Thanks for the input about readability vs lines of code. Will take note of that.